# Using Google Vision API to Predict Score of User-Specified Labels

Tags: python, image-recognition, google-cloud-vision, image-classification

Suppose I have an image of a [rainbow](https://artprojectsforkids.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Rainbow.jpg) and would like to use Google Vision API to predict the `score` for a set of user-specified labels, for example:

```
0    Rainbow:   0.965621
1    Sky        0.887454
2    Artwork    0.813930
3    Giraffe    0.015654
4    Coffee     0.012483
```

The following [Google Vision API code](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels#vision_label_detection-python):

```
def detect_labels(path):
    """Detects labels in the file."""
    from google.cloud import vision
    import io
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = vision.Image(content=content)

    response = client.label_detection(image=image)
    labels = response.label_annotations
    print('Labels:')

    for label in labels:
        print(label.description, label.score, label.mid)
```

Returns the following labels and score values:

```
  description       score          mid
0     Rainbow    0.965621    /m/0b48hv
1  Vertebrate    0.924276     /m/09686
2       White    0.921867     /m/083jv
3     Cartoon    0.918200     /m/0215n
4     Product    0.908071    /m/01jwgf
5       Green    0.907698     /m/038hg
6    Organism    0.875143     /m/05nnm
7     Textile    0.873498     /m/0dnr7
8   Rectangle    0.853343     /m/0j62f
9        Font    0.841818   /m/03gq5hm
```

Since only the 'top 10' labels are returned, I do not have the `score` for labels such as `'Coffee'` and `'Giraffe'`.

1. Is it possible to return more than 10 labels? Or is this a limitation of Google Vision API?
2. Instead of returning the top 10 labels, can I use Google Vision API to predict the likelihood of a user-specified label? For example, predict that the likelihood of `'Coffee'` is `0.012483`?
3. Is it possible to access **all** label `descriptions` and `mid` values? According to [EntityAnnotation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageResponse#EntityAnnotation), `mid` is an 'opaque' entity ID, however it states that some values are apparently available in [Google Knowledge Graph Search API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/). Does 'opaque' in this context mean that Google does not share their full list of labels?

I understand I can [train my own AutoML Vision model](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/beginners-guide#is_the_vision_api_or_automl_the_right_tool_for_me) and define my own labels, however it seems silly doing this since I'm happy to use Google's existing label categorisation. I just want more access to label data. Is there a way I simply can request the `score` of a chosen `mid` for a given image?

Note: I am happy to explore an alternative API if the data I need is not accessible via Google API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes it is possible return more than 10 labels. Just adjust the `max_results` in the request to do that.
2. Yes, you can cross check the entered user-specific label on the response from the API.
3. No, the labels used by Google are in a repository that is continuously growing in numbers which is probably in millions.

I did a different approach on using Vision API wherein I used [batch_annotate_images()](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/vision_v1/image_annotator.html#google.cloud.vision_v1.services.image_annotator.ImageAnnotatorClient.batch_annotate_images) and used a [request](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/vision_v1/types.html#google.cloud.vision_v1.types.AnnotateImageRequest) to define the type of detection that will be used. With this approach I can easily control the [features](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/vision_v1/types.html#google.cloud.vision_v1.types.Feature) to be used to process the image.

```
def detect_labels(path):
    """Detects labels in the file."""
    from google.cloud import vision
    import io
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = vision.Image(content=content)
    features = [{"type_": vision.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION, "max_results": 11}]
    requests = [{"image": image, "features": features}]

    response = client.batch_annotate_images(requests=requests)

    for image_response in response.responses:
        for label in image_response.label_annotations:
            print(u"description : {}".format(label.description))
            print(u"score : {}".format(label.score))
            print(u"mid : {}\n".format(label.mid))
```

Used this [image for testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odhRP.jpg) and changed the value of max_results to 3 and 11.

Changed `max_results` to 3:
[image]

Changed `max_results` to 11:
[image]

Comment: 1. I added a max_results parameter and this did indeed return more results. However it looks like the number of results returned is limited by the score value, with results only returned if the score is at least 50%. For example, even if max_results=100, only 43 results are returned if there are only 43 results with a score >= 0.5.

Comment: 2. I imagine cross-checking would be possible for labels which have a score >= 0.5, but not possible for labels with a score < 0.5 since these are not returned by the API? I guess this means I can assume that if a label is not returned by the API, it must have a score < 0.5, but I imagine this also means that more detail on the actual value of the label (e.g = 0.24548) is not possible.

Comment: @Alan Yes you are correct, by default Vision API only returns scores > 0.5 and currently there is no option to adjust that.